# What is the procedure for selling California registered vehicle to out of state buyer?

Tags: california, vehicle, dmv

My friend is planning to sell a vehicle to an out of state buyer. We were having a debate about the process and neither of us are absolutely certain about the process. The vehicle in question is located in California and registered there. It does not have any lien on it. There are multiple buyers that are interested and some of them are out of state. I think my friend needs to follow the same process for in-state buyers which is essentially Bill of Sale, Signing the Title, Smog Check report and filing the Notice of Transfer and Release of Liability. Is there anything else that my friend needs to do to notify the DMV that the vehicle will be registered out of state? The vehicle is also fairly new < 10 years old so I think we can skip the Smog Check. I think she can take the plates off and the buyer can get Transit Tags from their state. But she thinks she will just leave the plates on. Given this is an out of state buyer are there any legal gotchas she should be aware of? Should the buyer fill out the CA DMV's Title Transfer form?

Comment: @mkennedy that section is not valid for private party sales. If you look closely, REG 51 form is only available to dealers. It is not available to private sellers. Rest assured, I read through the DMV website before I posted this question.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I didn't look clearly at the page title. I'll delete my comment.